# Event-based communication between microservices

Tags: microservices, node.js, pubsub

I'm currently looking into [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) to use as the framework for a new e-commerce project. The goal is to build multiple loosely-coupled services, which can communicate with each other using the [pub/sub messaging pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). NestJS offers some great integrations out-of-the-box with tools like Redis, NATS and RabbitMQ. I've read that Kafka is also supported, but that isn't properly documented yet.

The problem I have is about decision-making. After reading lots of material about event-based systems and how they work, I still don't have a clear vision on what tool to pick.

---

**1) I think I need a message broker that can queue messages to ensure they get delivered (eventually) to the subscribers.**

This is because I might have a `CatalogueService` which emits events such as `product_created`. Services like a `CartService` and `OrderService` should also hold a copy of the product data and these products should be up-to-date. I can't afford to have old prices in the `OrderService` as the price calculations would be off. Also, if a service goes down, it can be restarted and properly process any unprocessed messages in the queue.

**2) I think I need a message broker that can support FIFO (first in, first out) queues.**

This is because I might have two `product_edited` events that should be processed in the right order to prevent corrupted data. If a store manager changes a product price twice, the latter price should be considered as most actual.

---

I used the words "I think" in front of the two requirements as I'm not a 100% sure if my thinking is correct. Therefor I'm curious to see what your thoughts and experiences are. Any tips, tricks or advice would be highly appreciated!